# How to define a pattern which is valid for all files in the directory including subdirectories?

Tags: makefile

I'm writing a pattern for compiling all `.c` file in the `test` directory.

Details of the directory is as follows:

```
./prj/makefile

./prj/test

./prj/test/test1/a.c
./prj/test/test1/b.c

./prj/test/test2/c.c
./prj/test/test2/d.c

./prj/test/e.c

...
```

Just a demo. This is my content of `makefile`:

```
# Find all files
rwildcard := $(wildcard $1$2) $(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2))

# All .c files
SRC_FILES := $(call rwildcard,test,*.c)

# All .o files
OBJ_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:.o=.c)

all : $(OBJ_FILES)
    echo $(OBJ_FILES)

%.o : %.c
    echo $@ $<
```

Make prints `No rule to make target '...'`. I think make need know path of `.o` files and `.c` files. But I don't know how to setting the path, Since there is so many `.c` files in my prj.

Because `OBJ_FILES` has includes all `.o` files. Then I guess the pattern should be like this:

```
    $(output_dir)/%.o : $(input_dir)/%.c
        echo $@ $
```

Since here may have many directories in ./prj/test, I cann't hardcoded it in makefile

Thanks for another friend, the above approach is right. since % can match many Multi-level directories。

Comment: Where do you want `b.o`? Should it be `/prj/test/test1/b.o`, or `/prj/test/b.o`, or something else?

Comment: It should be: /prj/test/b.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't really solve your problem because you still have not specified where the object files should go. All in a specific directory? Always in the parent directory of the source file? Somewhere else?

Regardless of how you resolve that, you can add all your source directories to [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) and have Make resolve the precise location while figuring out the dependencies.

```
VPATH=test:test/test1:test/test2

experiment: a.c d.c
        echo $^
```

will echo `test/test1/a.c test/test2/d.c` with full paths.

So with this you can remove the hard-coded directory names from your `%.o` rule and simply specify which `.o` files you want built for the `all` target.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get all c files in subdirectories:

```
$(wildcard */*.c)
```

Or also this to get all c files in subdirectories at any depth:

```
$(wildcard **/*.c)
```

Comment: I have already get all .c files and .o files. The key of problem is how to writing the dependence pattern.

Comment: @mi2think Do not write the dependency pattern. Use the `-MMD` preprocessor flag instead.